# Wpa & wpa2 enterprise, peap security, wifi is not connected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

Earlier I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Some days ago I removed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed new fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

In Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi was working properly. But now I've moved to Ubuntu 18.04 **WiFi no longer works**.

I have tried several solutions, but I cannot solve the problem.

**WiFi settings**

- wap & wap2 enterprise
- peap
- my identity
- domain (empty)
- no ca-cert. required
- auto
- m*****
- my user
- pass

(Side note - How can I report this problem to the Ubuntu development team?)

Comment: Was this an in-place upgrade or a fresh installation?

Comment: First i remove Ubuntu 16.04 and then after install Ubuntu 18.04 @Kevin

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w This is one of the work around which might be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot downgrade wpa\_supplicant to fix Wifi connection to a corporate network (WPA2) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w)