# Cannot downgrade wpa_supplicant to fix Wi-Fi connection to a corporate network (WPA2/PEAP with no CA certificate) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, downgrade, wpa-supplicant

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 (clean install, full wipe). Now I can no longer connect to the corporate network at my office (perhaps related to these bugs: [bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839?comments=all), [bug 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1761003)). What proved to fix this issue in Ubuntu 16.04 is the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690032/after-upgrade-to-15-10-wifi-to-a-corporate-network-wpa2-is-not-working-anymore); Downgrade `wpa_supplicant` to 2.1.

However, even with the linode repository, this fix can no longer be applied. There is no version for `wpa_supplicant` below 2.6 to the best of my knowledge for Ubuntu 18.04.

My question is this: How can I downgrade wpa_supplicant to 2.1 for Ubuntu 18.04?

Configuration needed for corporate the wifi connection:

- Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
- Checkbox No CA certificate required.
- Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2

Comment: Perhaps related are these launchpad issues:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839?comments=all
&
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1761003

Comment: I have not performed any of the proposed fixes to this answer and the launchpad issue to date. But the problem now seems resolved for me and others in the launchpad. I am not sure what changed, either a fix was pushed trough the regular Ubuntu 18.04 updates, or the corporation I work at have changed their Wi-Fi configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution and it is working flawlessly. Here are the steps:

1. Add Ubuntu Vivid and Xenial repos.

   ```
   $ cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivid.list
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse
   EOF

   $ cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
   EOF
   ```
2. Update your repo list.

   ```
   $ sudo apt -y update
   ```
3. Downgrade wpasupplicant and install libssl.

   ```
   $ sudo apt -y --allow-downgrades install wpasupplicant=2.1-0ubuntu7.3

   $ sudo apt -y --allow-downgrades install libssl1.0.0=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14
   ```
4. Setup priority for the recently installed packages.

   ```
   $ sudo echo -e "Package: wpasupplicant\nPin: release o=Ubuntu,n=vivid\nPin-Priority: 1001" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/vivid

   $ sudo echo -e "Package: libssl1.0.0\nPin: release o=Ubuntu,n=xenial\nPin-Priority: 1001" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/xenial
   ```
5. Restart your computer.

**Credits:** http://viranzo.blogs.upv.es/2018/09/11/downgrade-wpa_supplicant-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: You should add a warning to the answer or something, mixing repos is not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed sort of.  This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 MATE.

Need to get https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/2:2.4-1.1ubuntu1 version of `wpa_supplicant`.

Get those files ready to build:

```
wpa_2.4.orig.tar.xz                   1.7 MiB   a1e4eda50796b2234a6cd2f00748bbe09f38f3f621919187289162faeb50b6b8
wpa_2.4-1.1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz    101.0 KiB   05668f7d4cc9111c3760622199006e726da0bd7929340106380d7aac92853d4e
wpa_2.4-1.1ubuntu1.dsc                2.6 KiB   26ece998f27884d4c80c85088ecb1fd4217b1da6ed227729499f626707ff9af3
```

with something like

```
dpkg-source -x wpa_2.4-1.1ubuntu1.dsc
```

Install dependecies:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ debhelper libdbus-1-dev libssl1.0-dev libqt4-dev libncurses5-dev libpcsclite-dev libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libpcap-dev libbsd-dev libreadline-dev pkg-config qt4-qmake docbook-to-man docbook-utils android-headers
```

(these are described in the `.dsc` file)

then build it

```
cd wpa-2.4/
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -d
```

and it should spit some `.deb` files to install

like:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i wpasupplicant_2.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You will have some problems if you are inexperienced, but this should give you somewhere to start....

I promise it worked for me with an Intel wireless (`iwl` firmware and driver) which couldn't connect to the wpa2 enterprise tls with auth certs.  Now it works like it did in 16.04.

keywords to look up to help compile might be google:how to compile debian source code or https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu-18.04, but it didn't work.  Downgrading to `wpasupplicant=2.1-0ubuntu7.3` and `libssl1.0.0=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14` did though

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded an older version of wpasupplicant (2.4-1.1) and installed with:

```
dpkg -i wpasupplicant_2.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

It solved my problem.

The .udeb file for this older version of wpasupplicant is available for download on Launchpad: [wpasupplicant_2.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/2:2.4-1.1ubuntu1/+build/13706317/+files/wpasupplicant-udeb_2.4-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.udeb)