# PEAP enterprise/WPA2 WiFi Ubuntu not connecting

Tags: wireless, network-manager, system

When I try to connect to a PEAP enterprise WPA2 WiFi using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, it simply doesn't. It keeps trying to connect forever.

Nothing I tried worked, all the top anwsers from google failed and from here too.

I also tried downgrading wpasupplicant to version 2.1 but am unable to do so, if you can also help with that.

There is no CA certificate.

Can you give me some light on the issue?

Tip: if you are having the same trouble and have no solution, one poor workaround you can do is to just use your phone as a wifi-repeater, the connection is bad but at least works.

Comment: You're most probably facing this nasty bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot downgrade wpa\_supplicant to fix Wifi connection to a corporate network (WPA2 with no CA certificate) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w)