# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't connect to WPA/WPA2 Enterprise PEAP MSCHAPv2 network

Tags: networking, 18.04

I recently got Ubuntu 18.04, but it doesn't connect to my school wifi. Details:

- WPA/WPA2 Enterprise
- PEAP
- MSCHAPv2
- Credentials are correct

I've seen others saying to remove `system-ca-certs=true` from the network configuration file found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` but I can't find that line anywhere. Is it because I haven't upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 but got 18.04 clean? Or anything else? Is there another solution or a patch?

Comment: It's a nasty bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot downgrade wpa\_supplicant to fix Wifi connection to a corporate network (WPA2) in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w)

Answer (score -1):

I have this same issue, and have tried many suggestions online to fix it. I believe this is something that the network administrators specify.
My solution was just to install Windows in VirtualBox and use that to sign into the network, and then I am able to access it in Ubuntu.
Messy and not an ideal solution but it works.