# Cannot connect to my hostel WPA2-EAP wifi network

Tags: networking, wpa2

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 x86_64 
My wifi card is Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n 
I got my wifi working by installing bcmwl-kernel-source

I can connect to other networks on ubuntu (WPA2-PSK most of the time) 
I can connect to the network in question on my dual booted Windows 10.

I have tried a number of solutions but one of them have helped me the slightest.

I managed to fix this same problem on some other version of Ubuntu by simply altering my /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ file.

I have installed a couple of other tools like wicd but they haven't done any good, they might need to be removed, but I'm keeping them until the need arises.

I'm on the same machine on another network so I can send outputs, feel free to ask for them or any other stuff.

Thank you for any help.

Some extra info:
On windows 10 and on other ubuntu machines with different network cards, this network does not require a ca certificate.
There are multiple routers on each floor of my hostel, (repeaters if you will).

Comment: This bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1761003 / https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839, solutions proposed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wifi-connection-to-a-corporate-network-w

Comment: @pomsky IT WORKS.! I did know this was a bug, but the one you pointed at was way more specific. Thank You, have a good day.

Comment: Oh, the downgrade to wpasupplicant 2.1 and libssl 1.0.2,

Comment: It is a duplicate, couldn't find the original one.

Comment: Yes, ty again, I'm quite new around here.